Partially signing transaction with backend wallet and then signing it with frontend wallet as a feepayer
I'm trying to create a transfer transaction from my backend wallet to the frontend wallet. Fee payer should be the frontend wallet, but when I sign the transaction with the backend wallet, I get an error. I tried changing the fee payer to the backend wallet to then change it to the frontend one during signing with frontend wallet, which helped, but it seems to reset the signature from the backend (that or the problem is in the wallet adapter resetting all signatures on signTransaction method). What would be a way to tackle this problem?
This is my backend code:
const _pretx = new Transaction().add(
  web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: OwnerWallet.publicKey,
    toPubkey: req.body.publickey,
    lamports: reward
  })
);
console.log("Added ix")

_pretx.feePayer = OwnerWallet.publicKey;
_pretx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
console.log("Added blockchain info");

_pretx.sign(OwnerWallet)
console.log("Signed with backend key");

console.log(_pretx)
const _tx = _pretx.serialize({ requireAllSignatures: false, verifySignatures: false })
console.log("Sending tx");
return res.status(200).json({ tx: base64.encode(_tx) })

And this is frontend:
const decodedTx = base64.decode(res.data.tx)
const tx = Transaction.from(decodedTx)
console.log(1, tx)
tx.feePayer = publicKey;
// @ts-ignore
const signedTx = await signTransaction(tx);
console.log(2, signedTx)
const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTx.serialize())
console.log(signature)

This is the frontend console output: 

While I'm not entirely sure that the issue stems from the web3.js library version, it did seem to help to downgrade for a moment and then upgrade back up.
At the time of writing the question I was using v1.94.0 of @solana/web3.js, which I downgraded to v1.73.2 and then back up to the latest (at the time of writing this post) v1.95.3.
Second and probably main fix to the problem was to introduce Transaction.setSigners() method, which populates the transaction with public keys of the signers beforehand. The first public key is supposed to be the feePayer as per documentation. This method is deprecated in versions above v1.82.0, but it's vital for this workflow to actually work, since adding new signers without having them populated beforehand seems to change the transaction enough in the frontend to reset the backend signature.
After adding that method we can add the recentBlockhash of the transaction and then sign it with the backend Signer, serialize the transaction, encode it with base64 and send it over to the frontend.
Full backend code will look like this:
const reward = 1_000000000;
const userPubKey = new PublicKey(req.body.publickey);
const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
const _pretx = new Transaction().add(
  web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: OwnerWallet.publicKey,
    toPubkey: userPubKey,
    lamports: reward,
  })
);
console.log("Added ix")
_pretx.setSigners(userPubKey, OwnerWallet.publicKey);
_pretx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
console.log("Added blockchain info");
_pretx.partialSign(OwnerWallet);
console.log("Signed with backend key");
console.log(_pretx)
const _tx = _pretx.serialize({ requireAllSignatures: false, verifySignatures: false });
console.log("Sending tx");
return res.status(200).json({tx: _tx.toString("base64")})

With the frontend things are way simpler now. We only have to get the transaction from the backend, decode it, deserialize it and send it to the blockchain using the sendTransaction() method from the useWallet() hook of the wallet-adapter-react library.
Full code of the frontend will look like this:
const decodedTx = Buffer.from(res.data.tx, "base64")
const tx = Transaction.from(decodedTx)
console.log(1, tx)
const signature = await sendTransaction(tx, connection);
console.log(signature)

Alternatively, you can sign the transaction with the frontend wallet separately and then send it to the blockchain using Connection.sendRawTransaction() method if that's your preferred workflow. This way the code will look like this:
const decodedTx = Buffer.from(res.data.tx, "base64")
const tx = Transaction.from(decodedTx)
console.log(1, tx)
const sign = signTransaction!;
const signedTx = await sign(tx);
console.log(2, signedTx)
const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTx.serialize())
console.log(signature)

If you want to look at the on-chain transaction details, here you go (explorer.solana.com).
My last detail would be that testing partially signed transactions using localnet seems extremely unstable and counterproductive, since frontend wallets don't seem to have a lot of features for developers unfortunately. So do your tests either on devnet or testnet.
Also giving credit to @Jonas H. for helping me figure out this issue.

you need to partial sign in the backend:
const transaction = await mintCompressedNft(
    CONNECTION,
    nftArgs,
    ownerWallet.publicKey,
    TreeAccount,
    CollectionMint,
    collectionMetadataAccount, 
    collectionMasterEditionAccount,
    feepayer
  );
  transaction.recentBlockhash = hash.blockhash;

  transaction.partialSign(ownerWallet);
  console.log("transaction " + transaction.instructions.length);
  
  const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({
    verifySignatures: false,
    requireAllSignatures: false,
  });

  const base64Transaction = serializedTransaction.toString('base64');

  res.status(200).json({
    transaction: base64Transaction,
    message: "OK",
  });

then in the frontend you can do:
const decodedTx = Buffer.from(jsonResponse.transaction, "base64");
        const transaction = Transaction.from(decodedTx);

        const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, CONNECTION, {
          skipPreflight: true,
        });

Here is a complete example:
https://github.com/solana-developers/one-milion-nfts/blob/main/next/app/page.tsx
https://github.com/solana-developers/one-milion-nfts/blob/main/next/pages/api/mint.ts

I saw your answer before on a similar issue. This didn't fix it and I get an Unexpected error on the frontend as I send the transaction.

i see, but in your code looks like you call sign instead of PartialSign. Also you are setting the feepayer in the backend and then you set it again in the frontend. Maybe leave out the one in the backend. Maybe thats the reason it gets overwritten.

There is inherently no difference between sign and partialSign other than sign overwriting every signature in the transaction and autofilling feepayer as the signer. If I remove feepayer in the backend, I get an error that it's required in the partialSign (which has to be the same as the signer publicKey), with sign the error disappears, but the frontend behavior stays the same.

Is the code open source somewhere so i can have a look?

I wish it was, but unfortunately I can only show code snippets. If you would need more context, I can provide it.

The signature may get lost because you are changing the transaction in the frontend. Try adding the correct feepayer from the frontend in the backend when you create the transaction allready.

It doesn't let me set a different fee payer when I partialSign or sign. I get an error akin to it telling me that the signer public key is not equal to the fee payer (TypeError: x.pubkey.equals is not a function), which is definitely weird. sign automatically sets the fee payer so it's not required. I was thinking of maybe somehow adding all public keys of signers beforehand, but I didn't find a way how to do it, since addSigners method is deprecated.

So if you set _pretx.feePayer = req.body.publickey; and partials sign with _pretx. partialSign(OwnerWallet) you get an error? Whats the exact error? Maybe thats a bug? Which version are you using?

I wrote the error above your comment - TypeError: x.pubkey.equals is not a function. I'm using the latest version of @solana/web3.js (1.95.3). I also tried lower versions, but it doesn't seem to make the error go away. If you got a suggestion for a version of the library you used, I'll try it!

Okay, downgrading was part of the solution. I will write the full solution in here now. Thank you so much for your help! I spent way too many nerve cells on this issue :)

Oh happy you figured it out!! I wonder if its a bug in 1.94 and was fixed in 1.95 maybe you were very unlucky :-/
